# 'int' object has no attribute 'output'

Tags: python, while-loop, python-3.9

This may be a silly question. I just created a function that divide a number and give remainder if the number is even else do some other mathematical operations in python.

```
def collataz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        output = number // 2
        return int(output)

    else:
        output = 3 * number + 1
        return int(output)

import sys

try:
    c = collataz(int(input("Enter int")))
    while c.output != 1:
        print(c)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit()
```

But when I run this code it gives this following error after asking for input `'int' object has no attribute 'output'` how can I fix this? and please also tell the reason why my code give this error so I can understand the problem. Please tell if something is not clear.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name `output` inside your `collatz` function does not have any meaning outside of it.  The value you `return` is just an int, which you're assigning to the name `c`.

I think you want the last part of your code to be something like:

```
    c = int(input("Enter int"))
    while c != 1:
        c = collataz(c)
        print(c)
```

Comment: It worked as it was supposed to after applying your solution. But can you please explain what this part do?      `c = collataz(c)`

Comment: `collataz(c)` calls the `collataz` function with the current value of `c` as its argument.  The `=` is the assignment operator; it takes the value on the right (which is the result of calling the function) and assigns it to the name on the left (which is the variable `c`).  Each time this line of code executes, it runs `c` through the function and replaces it with the result.